# Low FPS on all games on Acer Nitro 5 while it was working fine before

Tags: graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, opengl

I have an issue with my Acer Nitro 5 AN515-42-R6GG on Ubuntu 20.04

Since the beginning, when the computer was on for a while, I noticed that all my games were lagging. But now, they are lagging from startup.

I'm wondering if the games could be using the wrong GPU, or if there was a temperature problem and now the issue became permanent for some reason (temperature sensor HS maybe?), or if there could be another explanation.

Anyway, I tried to find out this by myself on the internet, but without success. Here is what I found until now:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
--
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-52-generic, LLVM 10.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

```
$ sudo radeontop
        radeontop unknown, running on POLARIS11 bus 01, 120 samples/sec         
                                         │
                   Graphics pipe   0,00% │
─────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────
                    Event Engine   0,00% │
                                         │
     Vertex Grouper + Tesselator   0,00% │
                                         │
               Texture Addresser   0,00% │
                                         │
                   Shader Export   0,00% │
     Sequencer Instruction Cache   0,00% │
             Shader Interpolator   0,00% │
                                         │
                  Scan Converter   0,00% │
              Primitive Assembly   0,00% │
                                         │
                     Depth Block   0,00% │
                     Color Block   0,00% │
                                         │
                 5M / 4091M VRAM   0,13% │
                 17M / 4089M GTT   0,41% │
      0,30G / 1,45G Memory Clock  20,69% │       
      0,21G / 1,27G Shader Clock  16,78% │
```

I would be very grateful if you could guide me.

Comment: If you think temperature might be the issue, try installing `psensor` and monitor the temps. By what you posted, it looks like the GPU is detected - not sure about if it is used. If you can, try and get `amdgpu` drivers and check if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: `Kernel driver in use: amdgpu` - > doesn't this mean that it is already the driver in use?

Comment: I didn't see that part, my bad.